# Как проверить пользователь Администратор или нет в Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel

Как проверить пользователь Администратор или нет, если админ то должен показать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим у вас в таблице `users` есть поле `is_admin`. Тогда во вьюхе будет так:

```
@if(Auth::user()->is_admin)
  пользователь администратор
@else
  обычный пользователь
@endif
```